# Android Compose how to update other Composable function better way？

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick, android-jetpack-compose

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufxHe.png)

I just wanna click button can log ComposeableB().or liek this , For example, if you click ComposableA, ComposableB will start an animation instead of updating the data.

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow please read [how-to-ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and please do not post code as images

Answer (score 0):

Although with Compose it is generally recommended to pass events to the app logic (like the ViewModel) instead of to the app UI ([Thinking in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#paradigm)), here's how your code could look like if you really need to do that:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue

@Composable
fun ComposableA() {
    var addLogEntry by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Column {
        Button(onClick = {
            addLogEntry = true
        }) {
            Text(text = "Log")
        }
        ComposableB(addLogEntry = addLogEntry) {
            addLogEntry = false
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ComposableB(
    addLogEntry: Boolean,
    onLogEntryAdded: () -> Unit
) {
    if (addLogEntry) {
        Log.d("Shadowmeld", "onAddLogEntry")
        onLogEntryAdded()
    }
}
```

Here you are passing a function as a second parameter (onLogEntryAdded, in lambda expression format) to ComposableB. This passed lambda expression will be called from ComposableB to modify state in ComposableA.

I believe there are better ways of doing this, like ComposableB being declared inside ComposableA (hoisting state to ComposableA) or, if that is not an option, passing the Button onClick event to a ViewModel that both ComposableA and ComposableB can observe.